# Is strict HTML4.01 more appropriate for mobile development?

Tags: html, mobile, html4

A short question: would it be more appropriate to use strict HTML4.01 over HTML5 for developing a website with maximum mobile device compliance in mind?

When testing my website in W3C's mobile validator it claims I'm missing various HTML4 tags, like meta-equiv content type and in fact claims I should use XHTML, which I personally avoid using.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "mobile". Things have moved a lot in the last 5 years.

http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile is a most excellent resource – you perhaps don't want to just drop it in as is, though that works, but it has a lot of information in there that is hard to find in other places.

If you are designing for Android and iOS, then HTML5 is by far the right decision. If you are designing for dumb phones, then things are a little different.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I suppose I'm referring mainly to Windows, android and iPhones when I say "mobile". I personally have a Windows phone.

Comment: Then HTML5 is the way to go – Mobile has really led HTML5. Well, apart from Windows Phones, but hopefully the Windows 8 phone OS will be a lot better.